# Is it possible to serialize an array to the root of an object with JMS Serializer?

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization, jms-serializer

Imagine I have a simple object, structured similarly to the one below:

```
Object (SomeClass) {
    $someOtherData (array) [
        ...
    ]

    $data (array) [
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value"
    ]
}
```

If I were to serialize this object with JMS Serializer to JSON, I'd get a result that has an identical structure, but with $data being on the root element, like so:

```
{
    "someOtherData": {
        ...
    },
    "data": {
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value"
    }
}
```

I need to have the content of the $data variable be on the root of the serialized result, i.e:

```
{
   "someOtherData": {
       ...
   },
   "key": "value",
   "key": "value",
   "key": "value",
   "key": "value"
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out there is an annotation for this. It's the `@Inline` annotation:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Inline;

// ...

/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @Inline
 */
protected $variables;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best method is using a SerializationHandler. Here you can find a bit of documentation: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers.

Comment: Hmmm, I have been trying that since I posted this question - only thing is, I keep getting 'null' as the result of the serialization, no matter what I return from the handler. Weird...

Comment: could you create a gist with object class file and SerializerHandler?

Comment: Nevermind! I found exactly what I was after. The @Inline annotation.